# ARM (thumb) firmware mod...how to turn few lines of ASM to code to make a mod

Tags: arm, firmware, thumb, ida

Have firmware disassmbled with IDA (ARM920 Core).. most is Thumb mode....some is ARM mode
Want to make some mods, in ASM.

What is the easiest way to turn few lines of ASM (well few dozen) into machine language.
Can some one suggest a FREE tool / how to.

I just downloaded WinARM. Comes with Programmers Notepad. Been few hours now, trying to make sense of it all... just to compile a few lines of ASM... and the MAKE file i made, is still not working (some thing about end of line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool that turns assembly code into machine code is called an assembler.  Any of the usual toolchains include one.  For ARM, you can try good old gcc.  Source & binaries available: http://www.gnuarm.com/

Running the assembler should be as easy as:

```
gcc -o example.o example.s
```

You'll have to replace `gcc` in the example with the name of your cross-compiler.  I think the one from the link I have above is `arm-elf-gcc`.

Comment: i've just come across this info here: http://home.iitj.ac.in/~sk/files/compiler-intro.pdf 

...says... apparently the arm-elf-gcc calls  arm-els-as  ... so i guess that's the one i want to use.

Comment: after compiling, you can extract the generated code from the example.o file using `arm-elf-objcopy -O binary -S example.o example.bin`